# Typescript move code to multiple files

Tags: typescript

I have code like that in my `app.ts` file:

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => { 
   //code
}

app.use(function(err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
  // code
});
```

How can I move this functions to separate `ts` file and then import them and use in my `app.ts`?

```
app.use(Func1);
app.use(Func2);
```

What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibilities if you need to separate your code across multiple files:

1. compile your code as multiple internal modules (namespaces) into a single output file,
2. compile your code as multiple external modules, and load them during runtime with a module loading system.

### Internal Modules

Also called namespaces, these are akin to namespaces in other languages, although using it is slightly different from that in, say, C#.

```
namespace RequestHandlers {
    export function Func1(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        // code
    }

    export function Func2(err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Of course, you can separate a single namespace across multiple files, just how you'd do it in, say, C#. In that case you'd have *two* additional files, and in each of them your code would be surrounded by the namespace block.

Importing in Typescript is nothing more than aliasing in this case:

```
import Func1 = RequestHandlers.Func1;
import Func2 = RequestHandlers.Func2;

app.use(Func1);
app.use(Func2);
```

Of course, you can reference them directly as well, without using the `import` statement. File ordering issues may arise, so make sure you use reference paths as well, using which the compiler will compile dependent files in order. A reference path indicates a file that should be compiled (and included in the output file) in advance.

### External Modules

External modules are what modules are called traditionally in Javascript. They are file based, each module a file. To use external modules, you need a module loading system, like RequireJS. The Node.js runtime environment comes with its own built-in module loading system.

Typescript will automatically consider a file with a top-level export or import statement as an external module:

**requesthandlers.ts**

```
export function Func1(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    // code
}

export function Func2(err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    // code
}
```

Importing modules using the external-style import statement is supported in the Typescript compiler if a module loading syntax is selected for compilation (in Visual Studio, this can be found on the Project Settings -> TypeScript Build page), but will not work without a module loading system at runtime:

```
import * as RequestHandlers from "requesthandlers"; // by filename, without extension

app.use(RequestHandlers.Func1);
app.use(RequestHandlers.Func2);
```

The `import ... from "..."` syntax is the ES6 module syntax, which is the preferred way to import in TypeScript.

Comment: what approach is best on your opinion?

Comment: I prefer _internal_ modules (namespaces), as it saves me from having to also include a module loading system. This way you reuse your application/library components by compiling their source with the project they are included into. Also, you can't distribute a single _external_ module over multiple files (since each file is a module itself), which I find a significant issue from a structuring perspective.

Comment: do you have any thoughts on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290579/import-cannot-find-module-when-internal-module-has-imports-declared/ ?

Answer (score -1):

a.ts:

```
export function Func1() {}
```

b.ts:

```
export function Func2() {}
```

app.ts:

```
import { Func1 } from './a';
import { Func2 } from './b';

app.use(Func1);
app.use(Func2);
```